# Non-orthogonal technique analogous to PCA

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

Suppose I have a 2D point dataset and I want to detect the directions of all the local maxima's of variance in the data, for example:

[image]

PCA does not help in this situation as it is an orthogonal decomposition and therefore cannot detect both the lines I indicated in blue, rather its output may look like the one shown by green lines.

Please recommend any technique which might be suitable for this purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Could you make available your example data set?
I would like to try something for you. Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Independent Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) should be able to provide you with s good solution. It is able to decompose non-orthogonal components (like in your case) by assuming that your measurements result from a mixture of statistically independent variables.

There are plenty of good tutorials in Internet, and quiet a few freely available implementations to try out (for example in [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) or [MDP](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/)).

When does ICA not work?

As other algorithms, ICA is optimal when the assumptions for which it was derived apply. Concretely,

1. sources are statistically independent
2. the independent components are **non-Gaussian**
3. the mixing matrix is invertible

ICA returns an estimation of the mixing matrix and the independent components.

When your sources are Gaussian then ICA cannot find the components. Imagine you have two independent components, $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, which are $N(0,I)$. Then,
$$
p(x_{1}, x_{2}) = p(x_{1})p(x_{2}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp \left( -\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp -\frac{||\mathbf{x}||^{2}}{2}
$$

where $||.||$. is the norm of the two dimensional vector. If they are mixed with an orthogonal transformation (for example a rotation $R$), we have, $||R\mathbf{x}|| = ||\mathbf{x}||$, which means that the probability distribution does not change under the rotation. Hence, ICA cannot find the mixing matrix from the data.

Comment: Yeah, it should (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_vs_pca.html), Thanks a bunch ! :D

Comment: This might turn into a really deep answer if you tell more; in particularly, decide to compare @Gottfried's proposal (PCA with oblique rotation) with your proposal (ICA), - what are differences and shortcomings of the two.

Comment: I see that this question has been replied partly. Check the edit adding a simple example for which ICA does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

There are PCA-like procedures for the so-called "oblique" case. In stat-software like SPSS (and possibly also in its freeware clone) PSPP one finds the equivalently called "oblique rotations", and instances of them named as "oblimin","promax" and something more. If I understand things correctly the software tries to "rectangularize" the factor-loadings by re-calculating their coordinates in an orthogonal, euclidean space (as for instance shown in your picture) into coordinates of a space whose axes are non-orthogonal perhaps with some technique known from multiple regression. Moreover I think this works only iteratively and consumes one or more degrees of freedom in the statistical testing of the model.
See wikipedia for [rotation-methods in factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis#Rotation_methods)
An article with an [example](http://jalt.org/test/PDF/Brown31.pdf) of comparision PCA and oblique rotation
The [reference-manual of SPSS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_factor_oblique.htm) (at the IBM-site) for oblique-rotations contains even formulae for the computation.

*[Update] (Upps, sorry, just checked that PSPP does not provide "rotations" of the oblique type)*

Comment: Hmm, after a third read I see, that your question is slightly different from the oblique-rotation-rationale: in your cloud of data it is not even that the mean is at the origin/that the data are not even centered, so you might have something else in mind than I've covered here in my answer. If this is the case, I can delete the answer later on...

Comment: Because oblique "rotations" are subsequent to the PCA, they cannot "see" the kind of situation illustrated in the question and therefore appear to have no more ability to identify the two components than PCA itself does.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with it, but Vidal, Ma, and Sastry's [Generalized PCA](http://www.cis.jhu.edu/~rvidal/publications/cvpr03-gpca-final.pdf) was made for a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already given some useful hints about techniques you can consider, but nobody seems to have pointed out that your assumption is wrong: the lines shown in blue on your schematic picture are NOT local maxima of the variance.

To see it, notice that the variance in direction $\mathbf{w}$ is given by $\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{w}$, where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ denotes covariance matrix of the data. To find local maxima we need to put the derivative of this expression to zero. As $\mathbf{w}$ is constrained to have unit length, we need to add a term $\lambda(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{w}-1)$ where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange's multiplier. Differentiating, we obtain the following equation: $$ \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{w} - \lambda \mathbf{w} = 0.$$

This means that $\mathbf{w}$ should be an eigenvector of the covariance matrix, i.e. one of the principal vectors. In other words, PCA gives you all **local** maxima, there are no others.

Comment: Hi, I do not have much background in mathematics, can you recommend me a good resource to learn about the things you mentioned above ? Thanks.

Comment: @Ahmed: I am not sure, it depends on what you already know. I guess you would need decent textbooks on linear algebra and analysis. This is pretty basic stuff, should be covered in any decent textbook.